# Why are the first and last items of my ListView telepathically linked?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm trying to get a ListView to toggle the background color of its elements when they are selected (this is for selecting songs to add to a playlist). I've been mostly successful, but for some reason whenever the ListView is longer than the screen, selecting either the first or last item also toggles the background of the other. I keep track of whether an item is selected or not in an array of booleans called selectedStatus, and there's not a problem there, so it's purely a UI problem.

Here's the relevant section of the code:

```
boolean selectedStatus{} = new boolean[songsList.size()];

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    lv = getListView();

    // listening for song selection 
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            int viewPosition = position - lv.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            if(selectedStatus[position]){
                selectedStatus[position] = false;
                View currentEntry = lv.getChildAt(viewPosition);
                currentEntry.setBackgroundResource(R.color.footercolor);
            }
            else{
                selectedStatus[position] = true;
                View currentEntry = lv.getChildAt(viewPosition);
                currentEntry.setBackgroundResource(R.color.selected);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

There must be some implementation detail about ListViews that I'm missing, but I can't figure out why this would be happening.

EDIT: I've realized with more testing that it actually links all list elements with positions which are equal mod 12, I just wasn't looking at a long enough list. This seems much less weird, it's just reusing elements, and I'll have to look into this ViewHolder idea.

Since a few people asked, this is all the code I have for making an adapter and populating the list:

```
// Adding items to ListView
ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
        R.layout.playlist_builder_item, songnamesList);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: How are you setting your listview items? I need to know what you are using for your adapter? Do you have your own extending baseAdapter or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you might need to create a proper `ListAdapter` and implement a `ViewHolder`.

The ViewHolder avoids the layout reuse that Android `ListView` implements, so as you can do slightly more complicated things by relying on the `Views` being the same as before.

You should hold onto the `View` that you're changing in a static class. For example:

```
static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView backgroundItem;
}
```

Then in your Adapter's `getView` method you want to get hold of that `ViewHolder` and if we are creating a new view, we set it to be new, otherwise we reuse the old view that we have set as a tag to the original.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  ViewHolder viewHolder;

  if(convertView == null){
      // Inflate the view as we normally would
      // Create a new ViewHolder
      // Set our ImageView to be equal to viewHolder's backgroundItem  
      // final step
      convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
  }else{
      // use the original ViewHolder that was already saved as a tag
      viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
  }

   // Set the background as per your own code

   // Return the convertView
   return convertView;
}
```

Don't forget to set your Adapter to your listview by calling the ListView [setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setAdapter%28android.widget.ListAdapter%29) method

A decent tutorial which incorporates creating an `Adapter` and a `ViewHolder` can be found [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html).

Further reading:

- [Vogella article](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) on ListViews
- [Android Developer post](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) on ListViews

Comment: Thank you for a very good explanation of what I was doing wrong. This together with R Quijano's linked post in the below comment got things working.